# Comparing asymptotic growth of logarithmic functions by reasoning

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

As an exercise, we're sorting functions according to their asymptotical growth. When comparing these two functions, I'm getting stuck:

$n^2/(\log_2 n)^3$ versus $n \log_2 n$.

Using limits I am eventually able to figure out that the first one grows faster, but I'm actually looking for a way to do this without using limits.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you're trying to write a formal proof the easiest way is probably to divide them and take the limit.  If you just want an intuitive understanding, I would just say that the logarithm function grows very slowly, so if there are more rapidly growing factors you can ignore the logs on both sides.  We have $n^2 \gg n$ for large $n$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Ah, that makes sense. Still getting used to portions of the formula being insignificant.